# Android Time Synchronization in UTC

Tags: android, datetime

I have an application that relies heavily on current timestamps. Currently, when user submits a request, I get the current timestamp in UTC using `System.currentTimeMillis()`. While this works fine, it becomes a problem when the user starts manipulating their `Date/Time` on their device and would result as inaccurate timestamps.

Why do it on the client then? Why not just handle it on the server? Well, my application needs to work offline. All my requests get pushed into a `jobQueue` when connectivity to the internet is unavailable. In these cases, I must have the original time wherein the user did the action so if I submit a request at `4:02pm`, but due to network problems, server will only receive it around `7:30pm`, server MUST know that I sent the request at `4:02pm`.

**Now what options have I considered?**

1. Upon user login, I sync the device time with the server time and store that time locally. If any user manipulation occurs while the user is logged in, I'll have a `BroadcastReceiver` listening in onto any intents of `Date/Time` manipulation, then store the offset so that whenever a user submits a request, I will calculate the synced time with the offset to ensure the timestamp is accurate.
2. Have a server sync api done in the backend and set up a service within my application to continuously sync up with the server time and look for any drift while also listening in onto any user manipulation.
3. Use push notifications and listen downstream for time synchronization adjustments while also listening onto any user manipulation.
4. I could also make use of the `NTP` servers to synchronize time with my device.

I'm not entirely sure which would be the most optimal (assuming I have listed down all the possible solutions). If there are other solutions I haven't thought of, please let me know.

P.S. If I happen to use the `BroadcastReceiver` to listen onto any datetime manipulation on the device, how would I even calculate the offset in that?

Comment: Use local timezone from mobile app.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It has been some time since I asked this question and there hasn't been any elegant answers to the problem so after some research and some trial and error, I decided to take the NTP route and after some digging around, I found a nice library that does the entire thing for you.

It can be found here:

[NTP TRUE TIME](https://github.com/instacart/truetime-android)

Credits to these guys who had made life a lot easier.

You must sync with the ntp servers just once and from there on, they will calculate the Delta for us giving us accurate UTC regardless of `SystemClock` time.

Answer (score 0):

For time synchronization you can implement like getting time zone from server. Once we have timzone we can get the current time of server.

Comment: Seriously? I don't even think time zone is the issue here when we're dealing with UTC...

Comment: I meant say is if we have server time zone that means we ca get the server time by using time zone? Even without network

Comment: So you're saying to use something like this:

`Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance("TIME_ZONE");` right? If so, user can still manipulate the time on their phone.